# How to use jython within VBScript

Tags: vbscript, jython

I want to run jython using command line from Vb Script. Depend upon return value i want to execute some logic in VBScript. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that when you say "run jython" you mean "call a jython script from vbscript".  This also assumes your environment is setup so that your jython scripts are executable.  If my assumptions are wrong, please clarify your question.

```
Set myshell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim cmd, result
cmd = """C:\path\to\jython\script.py"" [params]"
result = myshell.Run(cmd,0,true)

If result = x then
    <do something>
ElseIf result = y then
    <do something else>
Else
    <do another thing>
End If
```

Comment: Can we get return value from Python script to VBScript without using command line parameter?

Comment: Sorry - I'm not following you.  Could you clarify?